# My visitor class has private operator(), can I friend std::visit?

Tags: c++, friend, variant

I need to `std::visit` a `std::variant`, but my visitor `class` has `private` `operator()`. Since my reviewers apparently do not like me making those `public`, can I `friend` `std::visit`?

I would also need it to be able to compile both in **GCC** and **Clang**, so the signature I would need to provide after the `friend` keyword need to work with both.

```
class Visitor
{
...
private:
    void operator()(TypeA&);
    void operator()(TypeB&);
...

friend ::std::visit // here is where I am not sure what to write
};
```

Comment: You can make it a friend in a limited fashion, but even that doesn't guarantee anything since a standard library implementation can have as many layers of abstraction down from `std::visit` as it wants (not to mention changing them between version). Considering visitation is a known idiom, and public operators are the norm, I'd like to have w/e your reviewer is smoking too. Part of doing code review is not just implementing w/e you are told by a reviewer, but also knowing how to push back and communicate why something should be done a certain way.

Comment: "Since my reviewers apparently do not like me making those public" why? Any workaround will eventually effectively make them available to the outside of the class in some way and the most simple way to do that is to make them public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is implementation-defined, where exactly the functor is actually called in the context of `std::visit`, you will eventually end up with platform-dependent code - at best.
Since your `visitor` class is supposed to appear in the same expression as your variant, you will need at least one interface function to do that. In order to limit the interface, I may do it like this:

```
using myvariant=std::variant<TypeA,TypeB>;
class Visitor
{
...
private:
    class proxy{
    public:
        proxy(Visitor & that): self{that}{};
        void operator()(TypeA&)&&;//proxy is always rvalue
        void operator()(TypeB&)&&;
     private:
        Visitor &self;
    };
...
    void operator()(myvariant& v)//this is my interface function.
    {std::visit(proxy(*this),v);};//only time I use proxy
};
...
myvariant myval;
...
Visitor myvis;
...
myvis(myval);
```

With this design, I avoid the `friend`ship anti-pattern and expose only one interface function.

Answer (score 2):

`std::visit` is a template. That alone is not the biggest issue, but what StoryTeller tells in a comment: It is not necessarily `std::visit` that will call the `operator()` and then you are out of luck because befriending is not transitive to other calls that `std::visit` might make.

You can use a class that is friend and forwards to the private methods:

```
class Visitor {
    void operator()(TypeA&);
    void operator()(TypeB&);
    friend struct PublicVisitor;
};

struct PublicVisitor {
    Visitor& vis;

    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T&& t) {
        vis.operator()(std::forward<T>(t));
    }
};
```

Last but not least, you should talk to your reviewers. Your requirements are contradicting. On the one hand you should keep `operator()` private on the other hand you need to access it from outside. You cannot have both, and if I had to choose between working code and reviewers, I'd pick the former. Also the above can be considered a workaround. Effectively it makes `operator()` accessible from outside the class. If the user can use `PublicVisitor` together with `std::visit` they can also use it in all other cases when they want to access `operator()`. The simple way to make `operator()` accessible is to make it public. Reviewers should not make you write code that is more complicated than necessary. Maybe it is necessary to keep it private, but its not apparent from what you say.